# not able to bind Text file content .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, tinymce

I am trying to bind text saved at a location as mentioned in Code below.
The text file is accessible and able to bind content to controls on ASP page, but not able to bind to [**tinyMCE**](http://www.tinymce.com/) control!
Page just keeps Loading for infinite time!

### Code:

```
If ddlQuestions.SelectedValue = 0 Then
    Dim lineOfContents As String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\FAQs\Answers.txt")

For Each line In lineOfContents
    Dim regex As New Regex("<span id=""s(.*)"" class=""abc"">")
    Dim v = regex.Match(line)
    Dim s As String = v.Groups(1).ToString()
    If Convert.ToInt32(s) = ddlQuestions.SelectedValue Then
        Dim regex1 As New Regex("<span id=""s" + s + """ class=""abc"">(.*)</span>")
        Dim v1 = regex1.Match(line)
        Dim s1 As String = v1.Groups(1).ToString()
        'txtAns: Editor TextArea
        txtAns.Text = s1 'getting text value in s1
        GoTo end_of_for
    End If
Next
end_of_for:
End If
```

### Content in Text file:

> ```
> <span id="s1" class="abc">The database management system.</span>
> <span id="s2" class="abc">Relational Database Management system (RDBMS).</span>
> <span id="s8" class="abc"><div class="code"><pre>A table</pre></div></span>
> <span id="s9" class="abc"><div style="font-size:20px"><i>The lead</i></div></span>
> <span id="s10" class="abc"><p>Test <em>Answer</em></span>
> ```

Here, while debugging NO ERROR occurs, no message is displayed. Also no error is being captured by Firebug as well!

I've referred [This Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191762/whats-the-best-wysiwyg-editor-currently-available-jquery-suppport-integration/3192178#comment3288948_3192178) about tinyMCE editor, but didn't get any solution on that.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me value of "line" string?

Comment: @QuanNguyen, added text file content in Question.

Comment: Oh sorry, what I mean is "s1", it contains only plain text?

Comment: whatever text between tag `<span>` will be considered in s1

Comment: Oh, so how about !IsPostBack, did you check it in the Page_Load event?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if so did you try this?

```
txtAns.InnerHtml = s1;
```

Because line string is a html element so I think it can work if you use InnerHtml property.

Comment: buddy, btw control is : `<asp:TextBox ID="txtAns" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="20" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>`